# Phalconphp flash SESSION messages after redirect doesnt show

Tags: php, phalcon, flash-message

I have a prepared AccessControll plugin for cheking access to resources and actions, so when i set flash message in plugin and then redirect to the login page the message doesn't show.

I have in access control plugin lines:

```
if(!$role || !$moduleAcl || !$moduleAcl->isAllowed($role,$controller,$action)){
      $this->flash->warning('Nemáte oprávnění na provedení této akce.');
      if(!$moduleAcl->isAllowed($role, 'index', 'index')){
            $auth = \Core\Auth::logout();
      }
      else {
           return $this->response->redirect($module.'/');
      }
}
```

In, base controller i have a line:

```
if(!$identity)
{          
   return $this->response->redirect('manager/auth/');                      
}
```

Can someone tell what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I have been using PhalconPHP too, and using Volt template engine with that, i had layout, and in top of the layour i had like
    `{{ flash.output }}` and template did output the flash messages at the top of my layout, 
or have you set them up in the config.php or bootstrap?

Comment: Have you tried `{{ flash.output }}`?

Comment: Yes yes, i know the framewok as well, but i have problem just with this one.

Comment: I had have that :) the problem it must be in something else.

Comment: You use session flash or simple flash?
check maybe this - http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/flash.html - i don't have Phalcon project on local computer, I'll check out on work station tomorrow, 
`Implicit Flush vs. Session¶
[..] temporarily storing the messages in session to be shown later. When should you use each? That usually depends on the type of redirection you do after sending the messages. For example, if you make a “forward” is not necessary to store the messages in session, but if you do a HTTP redirect then, they need to be stored in session:`

Comment: I have using session flash. Session flash and storage is memcache :)

Comment: `$frontCache = new Phalcon\Cache\Frontend\Data(array('lifetime' => 172800));
$cache = new Phalcon\Cache\Backend\Memcache($frontCache, array(
     'prefix' => $config->cache->prefix,
     'host' => $config->cache->host,
     'port' => $config->cache->port,
     'persistent' => false
    ));`

Comment: Michael, i mean that you don't understand what i said. I have session flash and the sessions are using the memcache storage. So problem is in something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a solution for that:

```
<?php
namespace Core\Http;

/**
 * Description of Response
 *
 * @author softdream
 */
class Response extends \Phalcon\Http\Response {
    //put your code here

    public function redirect($locationPath = null, $baseUrl = null, $statusCode = null) {
        if($statusCode){
            $this->setStatusHeader($code);
        }

        if(substr($locationPath, 0,1) === '/'){
            $locationPath = substr($locationPath, 1);
        }

        header("Location: ".$baseUrl.'/'.$locationPath);
        exit;
    }

    protected function setStatusHeader($code){
        header("HTTP/1.0 ".$code);
    }


}
```

This will resolve all problems with showing flash message after redirect, the problem is that phalcon doesn't stop script when redirect, so it can render some data before redirect.

I think that disabling view is not a good and cleaned solution how to do it :)

Comment: Yes this is exactly the issue and I think you have quite nice resolution here. I will go with that in next projects!

Comment: And plus this resolve the problem with $this->response->redirect("/module/controller/...."); Phalcon factory response class doesnt support "/" at the start :)

Comment: If you are interested in open-source projects, feel free to contribute this to our "core" lib here: https://github.com/vegas-cmf - cheers!

Comment: Ok i can do it later :) but now i have a lot of work :) but for you can be helpful my AutoRouting class :) https://github.com/softdream/Phalcon-autorouter ( but i must commit new version with lot of bugfixes and added new support url )

Comment: I apologise for commenting on such an old post - but how do you actually employ this solution (i.e how do you make this response class be used instead of the default)?

Comment: In two simple way: first find in your bootsrap or in your logic where u have define "response" when u not have defined, define it like this: 
$di->set('response',function(){
    return new Core\Http\Response();
});

Answer (score 1):

In you controller just put

```
$this->view->disable();
```

before

```
$this->redirect();
```

It will help. That was unexpected for me as well some time ago ;)

Comment: Yes it will resolve the problem but this is not clean and best solution, i was found where is the problem and i describe it below :)